# exprees.js res.cookies can not created cookie in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express

res.cookie() created cookie but browser not showing cookie, not stored cookie,but when i trying postman,the postman showing the ccokie

res.cookie("access_token",token,{secure:true,httpOnly:false})
res.cookie() created cookie for postman not for browser,I can not find about this problem resolving issue

Comment: secure:true will only set the cookie if the connection is made with https, is that the case? If the cookie did get sent, you should be able to see why the cookie isn't being set in the browser dev tool.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your code so I can't guess what was wrong.

But this demo code will work.

[image]

Demo code
Save as 'server.js'

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors()); // Add CORS middleware

const secretKey = 'secret code'; // Replace with your own secret key
const hardcodedUserId = 'steve'; // Replace with your own user ID
const hardcodedPassword = '1234'; // Replace with your own password

// Not real GET call should be post, it just no Frontend code for demo purpose
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { userId, password } = req.query;
  
    // Check if the provided userId and password match the hardcoded values
    if (userId === hardcodedUserId && password === hardcodedPassword) {
      const payload = {
        name: userId,
        role: 'User'
      };
  
      // Create a JWT token with the payload
      const token = jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, { expiresIn: '1h' });
  
      // Set the JWT token as a cookie named "access_token"
      res.cookie('access_token', token, { secure: true, httpOnly: false });
  
      res.send('Login successful');
    } else {
      res.status(401).send('Authentication failed');
    }
  });

app.get('/user-role', (req, res) => {
  // Retrieve the "access_token" cookie from the request
  const accessToken = req.cookies.access_token;

  if (accessToken) {
    // Verify and decode the JWT token
    jwt.verify(accessToken, secretKey, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send('Invalid token');
      } else {
        res.send(`Name: ${decoded.name}, Role: ${decoded.role}`);
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.send('No access token found');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

##### Install dependencies

```
npm install express cookie-parser cors jsonwebtoken
```

##### Run Express server

```
node server.js
```

##### mimic Login

Open Browser and Press <kbd>F-12</kbd>
Select Network `Tab` in DevTool

##### (Step 1)

```
http://localhost:3000/login?userId=steve&password=1234
```

##### Response Result (Step 4)

[image]

##### mimic access resource API

##### (Step 5)

```
http://localhost:3000/login?userId=steve&password=1234
```

##### Response Result (Step 8)

[image]